# When will rosdoc_lite be released to Hydro?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, rosdoc-lite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do most of my work on Hydro lately. It mostly works fine.

But, it's very annoying having to switch to a Groovy workspace for working on documentation.

Any estimate for when a Hydro version might be released?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65253/when-will-rosdoc_lite-be-released-to-hydro?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2013-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just released it today.  It should be built in the next few hours into shadow-fixed and will go into the next hydro sync to public.

PS a better forum is probably ros-release for this sort of request.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-06-17**:
Thanks, Tully! I'll do that for similar issues in the future. I considered opening an issue, but that seemed more "demanding" than I wanted.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-06-17**:
We basically need a request for package release/call for maintainership process.  And I hope to use the ros-release list for that.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-06-17**:
Seems reasonable.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-06-18**:
I'll maintain `rosdoc_lite`, if you want. I might ask for help in a few areas, but I can do most of the release and maintenance work.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-06-18**:
That would be great.  I'll set you up with permissions.